# Rest - order GET response xml

Tags: java, xml, rest, get, jaxb

I' m getting this simple xml from rest GET method. Restful service is written in java.

```
   <gear>
      <price>355.95929799818884</price>
      <idGear>1</idGear>
      <year>1985</year>
      <name>GPS</name>
  </gear>
```

My question is how to change the order of xml? I want to have idGear as a first node. Is this basic or more complex than I think?
Thanks for help?

UPDATE:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name="gear")
public class Gear{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int idGear;
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private double price;
      //getters, setters
```

Comment: How is this generated, and why do you want to change the order ?

Comment: The xml is generated auto from mysql DB(hibernate). I think the ID should be the first node, just for more proper look

Comment: Can you show the class that is being serialized to make this XML

Comment: Using a floating point type to represent unit prices is not a very good idea.

Comment: It's an interface, the order shouldn't be of any interest...

Comment: I just added serialization class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlType` annotation and set a `propOrder` to control the order that elements are marshalled to XML.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"idGear", "name", "year", "price"})
@Entity(name="gear")
public class Gear{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int idGear;
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private double price;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html

Answer (score 2):

@XmlType annotation has an attribute propOrder that can be used. Here is from the documentation:

> The annotation element propOrder() can be used to customize the content model to be xs:all or xs:sequence. It is used for specifying the order of XML elements in xs:sequence.

[Javadoc for XmlType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html)

Answer (score 2):

Its no where related to Rest. It can be achieved at JAXB conversion only by using `proporder` in `@XmlType` annotation like.

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"idGear", "name", "year", "price"})
```